# implementation of md5 algorithm in c

Tags: c, hash, md5

I want to rewrite the md5 hashing algorithm for learning purposes so I used the wiki (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) and so far it works as intended if I put no string

```
$ ./hashing "" 
80 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 

00000080 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 

d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e  - my algo
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e  -
```

but not if I put any other string

```
$ ./hashing "a"
61 80 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 

00008061 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 

3a389d88a349727c6751e9acae0b0f37  - my algo
0cc175b9c0f1b6a831c399e269772661  -
```

(I'm comparing it using {echo -n "[STRING]" | md5sum} which is the one in the bottom)

here is the code I got

```
#include "../inc/hashing.h"

/* reminder of the struct
 *
 *  typedef struct  md5_s{
 *      uint64_t    size;       // size of input in byte
 *      uint32_t    buffer[4];  // current accumulation of hash
 *      uint32_t    input[16];  // input to be used in the next step
 *      uint8_t     digest[16]; // result of algorithm
 *  }md5_t;
 */

// shift amounts per round
const uint32_t S[64] = {7, 12, 17, 22, 7, 12, 17, 22, 7, 12, 17, 22, 7, 12, 17, 22,//    0..15
                        5,  9, 14, 20, 5,  9, 14, 20, 5,  9, 14, 20, 5,  9, 14, 20,//    16..31
                        4, 11, 16, 23, 4, 11, 16, 23, 4, 11, 16, 23, 4, 11, 16, 23,//    32..47
                        6, 10, 15, 21, 6, 10, 15, 21, 6, 10, 15, 21, 6, 10, 15, 21};//   48..63

// K[i] = floor(2^32 × abs(sin(i + 1))) precomputed table
const uint32_t K[64] = {0xd76aa478, 0xe8c7b756, 0x242070db, 0xc1bdceee,//  0..3
                        0xf57c0faf, 0x4787c62a, 0xa8304613, 0xfd469501,//  4..7
                        0x698098d8, 0x8b44f7af, 0xffff5bb1, 0x895cd7be,//  8..11
                        0x6b901122, 0xfd987193, 0xa679438e, 0x49b40821,//  12..15
                        0xf61e2562, 0xc040b340, 0x265e5a51, 0xe9b6c7aa,//  16..19
                        0xd62f105d, 0x02441453, 0xd8a1e681, 0xe7d3fbc8,//  20..23
                        0x21e1cde6, 0xc33707d6, 0xf4d50d87, 0x455a14ed,//  24..27
                        0xa9e3e905, 0xfcefa3f8, 0x676f02d9, 0x8d2a4c8a,//  28..31
                        0xfffa3942, 0x8771f681, 0x6d9d6122, 0xfde5380c,//  32..35
                        0xa4beea44, 0x4bdecfa9, 0xf6bb4b60, 0xbebfbc70,//  36..39
                        0x289b7ec6, 0xeaa127fa, 0xd4ef3085, 0x04881d05,//  40..43
                        0xd9d4d039, 0xe6db99e5, 0x1fa27cf8, 0xc4ac5665,//  44..47
                        0xf4292244, 0x432aff97, 0xab9423a7, 0xfc93a039,//  48..51
                        0x655b59c3, 0x8f0ccc92, 0xffeff47d, 0x85845dd1,//  52..55
                        0x6fa87e4f, 0xfe2ce6e0, 0xa3014314, 0x4e0811a1,//  56..59
                        0xf7537e82, 0xbd3af235, 0x2ad7d2bb, 0xeb86d391};// 60..63

uint32_t swap32(uint32_t x)
{
    return  ((x & 0xFF) << 24) |
            (((x >> 8) & 0xFF) << 16) |
            (((x >> 16) & 0xFF) << 8) |
            ((x >> 24) & 0xFF);
}

// main function calling other one
void    ft_md5(md5_t *md5, uint8_t *s)
{
    uint8_t *new_s;

    new_s = ft_md5_padding(md5, s,ft_strlen((char *)s));

    md5->buffer[0] = 0x67452301;
    md5->buffer[1] = 0xefcdab89;
    md5->buffer[2] = 0x98badcfe;
    md5->buffer[3] = 0x10325476;

    // run algo on each block of 512 bit

    uint32_t    block = 0;

    while (md5->size > block) 
    {
        ft_memcpy(md5->input, new_s + block , 64);// 512 bit / 8 (1 byte = 8 bit) = 64 byte
        for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++)
            printf("%02x ", new_s[i]);
        printf("\n\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
            printf("%08x ", md5->input[i]);
        printf("\n\n");
        ft_md5_algo(md5);
        block += 64;
    }
    free(new_s);
    ft_memcpy(md5->digest, md5->buffer, 16); // 128 / 8
}

// binary operation according to md5 algo (thx Wikipedia) 
#define E(B, C, D) ((B & C) | ((~B) & D))
#define G(B, C, D) ((D & B) | ((~D) & C))
#define H(B, C, D) (B ^ C ^ D)
#define I(B, C, D) (C ^ (B | (~D)))

// md5 algorithm according to Wikipedia
void    ft_md5_algo(md5_t *md5)
{
    uint32_t    i;
    uint32_t    A = md5->buffer[0];
    uint32_t    B = md5->buffer[1];
    uint32_t    C = md5->buffer[2];
    uint32_t    D = md5->buffer[3];

    i = 0;
    while (i < 64)
    {
        uint32_t    f;
        uint32_t    g;

        if (i < 16)
        {
            f = E(B, C, D);
            g = i;
        }
        else if (i < 32)
        {
            f = G(B, C, D);
            g = (5 * i + 1) % 16;
        }
        else if (i < 48)
        {
            f = H(B, C, D);
            g = (3 * i + 5) % 16;
        }
        else if (i < 64)
        {
            f = I(B, C, D);
            g = (7 * i) % 16;
        }
        f += A + K[i] + md5->input[g];
        A = D;
        D = C;
        C = B;
        B += ft_leftrotate(f, S[i]);
        i++;
//      printf("Iteration %u: A=%08x, B=%08x, C=%08x, D=%08x, f=%08x, g=%u\n", i, A, B, C, D, f, g);
    }
    md5->buffer[0] += A;
    md5->buffer[1] += B;
    md5->buffer[2] += C;
    md5->buffer[3] += D;
}

uint32_t    ft_leftrotate(uint32_t x, uint32_t offset)
{
    return ( x << offset ) | ( x >> (32 - offset));
}

// padding of the main string

unsigned char   *ft_md5_padding(md5_t *md5, uint8_t *s, size_t l)
{
    size_t  new_len = l;
    uint8_t *new_s;

    while(++new_len % 64 != 0);// 512 / 8
    md5->size = new_len;
    new_s = (uint8_t *)malloc(new_len + 1);
    ft_memcpy(new_s, s, l);
    new_s[l] = 0x80;

    size_t  i = l + 1;

    while (i < new_len)
    {
        new_s[i] = 0x00;
        i++;
    }

    return (new_s);
}
```

I print it in the main (which is in another file) using

```
for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    printf("%2.2x", md5.digest[i]);
```

(every already known function with a ft before is me who rewrite it and it work "exactly" like the official one I already tried to change it between the one I rewrite and the official one and nothing change in this prog at least)

so I already tried to switch between little-endian and big endian but it doesn't work (I'm currently using little endian as said in the wiki)

I tested the padding and it's okay I also tested (as you can see in the output) if the string (which is 64 * 8 bits) is well copied into the input I give to the algo (which is 16 * 32 bits) and it also seems okay

I assumed that my algorithm and constant are also good since it work with an empty string
it's been 2 day and I literally have no clue where the issue can be

here the updated version of the padding function in case someone need it

```
unsigned char   *ft_md5_padding(md5_t *md5, uint8_t *s, size_t l)
{
    size_t  new_len = l + 8;
    uint8_t *new_s;

    while(++new_len % 64 != 0);// 512 / 8
    md5->size = new_len;
    new_s = (uint8_t *)malloc(new_len + 1);
    ft_memcpy(new_s, s, l);
    new_s[l] = 0x00000080;

    size_t  i = l + 1;

    while (i < new_len - 8)
    {
        new_s[i] = 0x00;
        i++;
    }
    // append the len to the padding
    new_s[i + 3] = l >> 21;
    new_s[i + 2] = l >> 13;
    new_s[i + 1] = l >> 5;
    new_s[i + 0] = l << 3;
    new_s[i + 7] = l >> 53;
    new_s[i + 6] = l >> 45;
    new_s[i + 5] = l >> 37;
    new_s[i + 4] = l >> 29;

    return (new_s);
}
```

it's now perfectly working thank's to you all
(how can i close this question ?)

Comment: Perhaps I missed it but I don't see where you append the length to the end of the last block.

Comment: Yeah, and for a zero byte string  it is still correct. It's kind of weird because you do seem to set it in a field, but then it is never used. Note that you may need to do some work to handle multiple blocks, especially if the padding / length (in bits!) doesn't fit.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk if you're talking about the padding i did it in the function at the very bottom which is used at the beginning of the main function

Comment: See [RFC 1321 sections 3.1 and 3.2](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1321#section-3.1).

Comment: ooooh i forgot that step thank's a lot :D and that's why it only work with an empty string it's cause the len is 0